# Magento SOAP v2: Email customer tracking number

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.6

I've been able to create a shipment and add a tracking number via SOAP, but I'm stuck figuring out how to email the customer their tracking number through the API. When creating a shipment I can send out an email, but a shipment has to be created before I can add a tracking number. I realize I can create my own email and send it out, but I'd rather stick to the API if possible.

Is there a SOAP method I can use to do this?

Creating the tracking number:

```
public function addTrackingNumber($trackingNumber)
{

    $shipmentID = $this->createShipment();
    return $this->client->salesOrderShipmentAddTrack(
                $this->sessionId,
                $shipmentID,
                "ups",
                "UPS",
                $trackingNumber
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The shipment API has an undocumented `sendInfo` endpoint. I'm not sure when it was added, so it may not be in your version of Magento, but you can look for it in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php`. In Magento 1.9.1.0 it looks like this:

```
public function sendInfo($shipmentIncrementId, $comment = '')
```

You'll need to work backwards from this to get the right code for the version of the API you're using. Here's what my request looks like (V1):

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order_shipment.sendInfo', array('100000001', 'an optional comment'));
```

In your application I suspect it would look something like this:

```
return $this->client->salesOrderShipmentSendInfo($shipmentID, 'an optional comment');
```

So you'll need to make three API calls: first to create the shipment (**not** sending the notification email), second to add the tracking number, and third to finally send the notification.

Answer (score 0):

this question is a bit outdated but I came across the same problem and solved it by looking at the Magento [API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html) for that method.
It says that you have to create the shipment with arguments if you want to notify the user too.

Comment: This results in the user getting a shipment notification email *without* tracking information.